# Passing a non-template function pointer into a template method

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, constants

I've searched through Google and stackoverflow and was unable to find something that addresses this situation:

1. I have a template with a method that takes a function pointer.
2. The function pointer itself is NOT a template, it's a normal function pointer.
3. The function pointer, however, has the template args used in its parameters

**File name: otherclasses.h**

> ```
> // This class is used as the template parameter
> class B
> {
>   public:
>     B() {}
>     ~B() {}
>
>     int getVal() const { return val; }
>     void setVal(int v) { val = v; }
>   private:
>     int val;
> };
>
> // This is just a static function
> class A
> {
>   public:
>     static bool someStaticFunction(const B* left, const B* right);
> };
>
> inline
> bool
> A::someStaticFunction(
>     const B* left, 
>     const B* right)
> {
>   return left->getVal() < right->getVal();
> }
> ```

**File name: templateheader.h**

> ```
> #include "otherclasses.h"
> template<typename T>
> class theTemplate
> {
>   public:
>     void insert(T val1, T val2)
>       {
>         stuff[0] = val1;
>         stuff[1] = val2;
>       }
>     bool usesSomeStaticFunction(bool (*funcp)(const T, const T))
>       { 
>         // will return true
>         return funcp(stuff[0],stuff[1]);
>       }
>   private:
>     T stuff[2];
> };
> ```

**File name: main.cpp**

> ```
> #include "otherclasses.h"
> #include "templateheader.h"
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main() 
> {
>   theTemplate<B*> foo;
>   printf("%d\n", foo.usesSomeStaticFunction(A::someStaticFunction));
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

The error from Visual Studio:

> ```
> error C2664: 'theTemplate<T>::usesSomeStaticFunction' : cannot convert 
> parameter 1 from 'bool (__cdecl *)(const B *,const B *)' to 
>                  'bool (__cdecl *)(const T,const T)'
>   with
>   [
>     T=B *
>   ]
> None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
> ```

Two ways around this problem:

1. Use `const void*` instead of `const T*`
2. Remove `const` from the parameters of the function pointer and anything that uses it.

Thanks for your help

***UPDATE***

Turns out there's a better solution - just move the `const` to the right of `B*` in the static function:

**File name: otherclasses.h EDITED**

> ```
> // This class is used as the template parameter
> // This is unchanged.
> class B
> {
>   public:
>     B() {}
>     ~B() {}
>
>     int getVal() const { return val; }
>     void setVal(int v) { val = v; }
>   private:
>     int val;
> };
>
> // This is just a static function
> // This is changed
> class A
> {
>   public:
>     // The "const" is moved to the right side of B*
>     static bool someStaticFunction(B* const left, B* const right);
> };
>
> // This is changed
> inline
> bool
> A::someStaticFunction(
>     // The function definition must match the function prototype...
>     B* const left, 
>     B* const right)
> {
>   return left->getVal() < right->getVal();
> }
> ```

Comment: Please do not add "solved" to your question title. If one of the answers helped you to solve the problem, [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220538) by clicking the check mark in the left margin. If none of the answers were useful and you figured out a solution of your own, post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `const T` becomes `T* const`, not `T const*`. One solution is to rework your code to not include the pointer in `T` (`T` = `B`) and include it in the template class instead:

```
template<typename T>
class theTemplate
{
  public:
    void insert(T* val1, T* val2)
      {
        stuff[0] = val1;
        stuff[1] = val2;
      }
    bool usesSomeStaticFunction(bool (*funcp)(const T*, const T*))
      { 
        // will return true
        return funcp(stuff[0],stuff[1]);
      }
  private:
    T* stuff[2];
};
```

Comment: Please take a look at the update I've added to the original post, at the bottom.